# Has a real or fictional ebook or ereader, been the title or main focus of a book or movie?

Tags: ebook-readers

It is not usual for technology or to play a title role in works of fiction. [Air Force One (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/)  as an example.  I am not looking for work that is both an ebook and a movie.  I am looking for something like [**Attack of the Killer (*ereader brand*)'**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080391/?ref_=nv_sr_2).  Or the [**The (*ebook title*) that changed the World**](http://books.google.com/books/about/Barbed_Wire.html?id=ixxWPgAACAAJ)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about movies rather than about ebooks: it is more suited to http://movies.stackexchange.com/. In addition, it is chatty and open-ended rather than practical and answerable.

Comment: The answer is not a movie, though one has been made. It is an ebook considered by some to be ["the standard repository of all knowledge and wisdom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_%28fictional%29) while the question may or may not be out of scope, it is not out of scope for being more suitable at movies.se.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ebook content.

Comment: @JasonDown - I'm afraid I have to disagree. It is not uncommon for technology to appear in science fiction well before in is actually invented. The question is more about the role of ebooks in society, as addressed in fictional media.

Comment: Well if two more people vote to reopen it then it will be reopened (you can always start a meta discussion and duke it out). My vote unfortunately is binding, so I'm not going to vote to reopen it (I didn't want to vote to close for that reason, but I felt it was off-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most famous is *The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy*, which is a travel guide that is mentioned periodically in the novel of the same name (and also its sequels) by [Douglas Adams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams).

Comment: I have the entire trilogy (of five books... figure that one out) queued up to read soon. Finally getting around to reading them.

Comment: @JasonDown Better to listen to the radio series which is the original

Comment: It is also the title of the movie [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/)

Answer (score 3):

"[The Diamond Age: Or, A Young Lady's Illustrated Primer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Age)" by Neal Stephenson is heavily focussed on the eponymous ebook reader.

> *At the age of four, Nell receives a stolen copy of an interactive
>   book, Young Lady's Illustrated Primer: a Propædeutic Enchiridion in
>   which is told the tale of Princess Nell and her various friends, kin,
>   associates, &c., originally intended for an aristocrat's child in
>   the Neo-Victorian New Atlantis phyle. The story follows Nell's
>   development under the tutelage of the Primer, and to a lesser degree,
>   the lives of Elizabeth and Fiona, girls who receive similar books. The
>   Primer is intended to steer its reader intellectually toward a more
>   interesting life, as defined by "Equity Lord" Alexander Chung-Sik
>   Finkle-McGraw, and growing up to be an effective member of society.
>   The most important quality to achieving an "interesting life" is
>   deemed to be a subversive attitude towards the status quo. The Primer
>   is designed to react to its owners' environment and teach them what
>   they need to know to survive and develop.*

Interestingly, the book almost certainly inspired the development of real-world ebook readers...

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't think of that one! Great story.

Answer (score 0):

The closest example that I can think of is in [I, Robot... You, Jane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Robot..._You,_Jane), an episode of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*. In this episode there is an old book which contains the life force of a demon. It is scanned in to a computer, releasing the demon into the computer network.